# XSLT Check if case occured in for-each and use the information

Tags: xslt

I don't have an approach for this, since I'm not able to change values of variables in XSLT.
Hopefully you could provide a proper approach for the following problem:

This is an example xml-node, to which I'll quote to explain the problem:

```
<information>
   <uselessNode1></uselessNode1>
   <uselessNode2></uselessNode2>
   <importantNode></importantNode>
</information>
```

What I essentially need here is to go through all the child nodes of the information node.
The importantNode is optional and the thing what I've to detect is whether this node is there or not.
If the importantNode is there it'll processed within the for-each loop and everything is fine.
In case of not having the importandNode, I've to show it's absence outside of the for-each loop.

So, if having following for-each loop in a template for the information node:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*"> 
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not( name() = 'importantNode')">
          USELESS
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
          IMPORTANT
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The output is "USELESS USELESS IMPORTANT". And if the important node is not there the output is
"USELESS USELESS". What I actually need to have instead of "USELESS USELESS" is a prompt, which shows that the important node is not there, e.g. "USELESS USELESS IMPORTANT_MISSING".

I tried to set a variable in the for-each loop if going in the -case and trying to
check this outside of the for-each loop throws an error, that the variable $importantFound is not declared or out of it's scope. I though declaring it before the for-each loop would help. Since I can't declare the variable before the for-each loop and change it's value in the otherwise case inside of the loop, I don't know how to solve this dilemma.

I hope the explanation of my problem was clear enough to understand. 
Thank You all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case of not having the importandNode, I've to show it's absence outside of the for-each loop.

So why can't you do exactly that - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="information">
    <xsl:for-each select="*"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(self::importantNode)">USELESS </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>IMPORTANT </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="not(importantNode)">IMPORTANT_MISSING</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's double checking, to which I'm not used to do as a software engineer, which is obviously inevitable using XSLT though.
I have to get used to it. Thanks! That was so obvious and does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, it is not double-checking, because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. If you wanted, you could use a recursive named template instead, with an additional parameter being passed from iteration to iteration. But that would be a lot more code, and much more awkward.